# mysqli if result > 0 do something

Tags: php, mysqli

How would i do this using mysqli?

```
$SQL = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = '$new_username'");
$result = mysql_num_rows($SQL);

If(!$result > 0) {
echo...
```

I tried:

```
$SQL = $mysqli->query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = '$utilizator");
$rezultat->num_rows($SQL);`
```

But I dont get any result.

Comment: Have to assign $rezultat->num_rows($SQL); to something $something = $rezultat->num_rows($SQL);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have started the query with `$SQL` .. continue with it as the object will be in that variable:

```
$SQL = $mysqli->query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = '$utilizator'");
$num = $SQL->num_rows();

if($num){
    // run your code here
}
```

Comment: But when Im trying If($num){ echo working} else { not working } even if the result is in DB i get the same answer "not working".

Answer (score 2):

you have to call store_result() after execution.

php.net has a wonderful php doc: http://www.php.net/manual/de/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php

for example:

```
$query = "SELECT Name, CountryCode FROM City ORDER BY Name LIMIT 20";
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {
  /* execute query */
  $stmt->execute();

  /* store result */
  $stmt->store_result();

  printf("Number of rows: %d.\n", $stmt->num_rows);

  /* close statement */
  $stmt->close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$number_of_rows = $SQL->num_rows;
```